# Netinet and netdb not found, c++ network libraries

Tags: c++, winsock

I was trying to run example codes to learn how to use winsock on c++ from the following links:
http://www.linuxhowtos.org/data/6/client.c
http://www.linuxhowtos.org/data/6/server.c

and the following libraries:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
```

was not at the default mingw libraries, and by trying to google it wasn't much of a success because it end up requiring other libraries to run.

if anyone have a link to the full library or it with the dependencies, i would appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What OS are you running? I ask because you mention winsock, but those aren't libraries you would find available to you if you're using windows.

Comment: I am actually using windows, could you direct me to an windows alternative then?

Comment: Use this tutorial - http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I removed both netinet/in.h and netdb.h library, added  and added the link: "-lwsock32", all working now.

Comment: Don't forget to call WSAStartup on Windows

Comment: I would recommend `-lws2_32` to link with winsock2.
See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62170418/fatal-error-netinet-in-h-no-such-file-or-directory/62179326#62179326 for more hints.