# fatal error: netinet/in.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c, sockets, udp

[SOCKET PROGRAMMING] [UDP SERVER]

I am trying to do Message encryption and decryption using UDP server.
Code is here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/message-encryption-decryption-using-udp-server/
But I am getting the following error:

```
fatal error: netinet/in.h: No such file or directory
```

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Please do not add unrelated tags. Missing headers for networking are not related to encryption.

Comment: What is your environment? Linux? Windows? else? What compiler?

Comment: my environment is windows

Comment: The UNIX related headers are not available there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Netinet and netdb not found, c++ network libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15561169/netinet-and-netdb-not-found-c-network-libraries)

Answer (score 3):

For the socket stuff on Windows you need `#include <winsock2.h>` and you will also need to link with `-lws2_32`.

In the beginning of your program you will also need to initialize the library like this:

```
static WSADATA wsaData;
int wsaerr = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 0), &wsaData);
if (wsaerr)
  exit(1);
```

and clean before exiting like this:

```
WSACleanup();
```

For the rest most basic networking functions are the same as on *nix platforms, except for `close()` which doesn't work on sockets, so you will need to do `closesocket()` instead.